# Why does this connection keep closing - SYN->SYN,ACK->ACK->RST,ACK

Tags: networking, tcp

I have an application that is sending web requests and after some variable period of time we start getting connection timeout errors. Analysis of the TCP/IP packets reveals the following occurring for each connection attempted:

No.     Time                       Source                Destination           Protocol Info

98635 2011-04-21 10:13:47.192237 172.22.3.250          172.22.3.100          TCP      [TCP Port numbers reused] httpx > http-alt [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460

98639 2011-04-21 10:13:47.192397 172.22.3.100          172.22.3.250          TCP      http-alt > httpx [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460

98641 2011-04-21 10:13:47.192425 172.22.3.250          172.22.3.100          TCP      httpx > http-alt [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0

98646 2011-04-21 10:13:47.192502 172.22.3.250          172.22.3.100          TCP      httpx > http-alt [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0

Once this happens the client machine must be rebooted to fix the issue. Restarting the client or server application, or rebooting the server have no effect. Comparison of the packet details between working and non-working messages reveal no differences for flags, etc.

Thank you,

Neil

Comment: Neglected to mention, we are using MFC classes: CInternetConnection, CHttpConnection, CHttpFile

Comment: There's no evidence here of a timeout, unless you are using a pathologically low timeout value. The client has decided to reset the connection 77ms after it decided to complete it. Something wrong with that client's hardware or operating system.

Answer (score 0):

`TCP Port numbers reused` is a clue. It might be your client is re-using the port numbers of the old connection which is supposed to be closed.

Does your client bind to a static source port?  If yes it might be that the clients operating system is rejecting the packets from the server because it thinks they belong to an old connection. The OS is rejecting the packets, that's why only a client reboot solves the problem. (Alternatively try waiting a couple of minutes).

When opening the connection on the client, don't assign a source port.

Comment: We are using the MFC HTTP classes so I have no control over the port assignment. We also see that it works for some time period even for reused ports, cycling several times around through the available ports before it starts failing.